# Find or insert if not found and return an error if the changeset is invalid

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to find an entity or insert it if it's not found.  Currently I'm doing it this way:

```
my_item = Repo.get_by(MyItem, var1: "some value") || Repo.insert!(MyItem.changeset(%MyItem{}, %{"var1" => var1}))
```

Is there a better way to do that? I also want to return an error if the changeset is invalid, currently this code isn't doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
item = case Repo.get_by(MyItem, var1: "some value") do
         nil -> insert_item("some_value")
         item -> item
end
```

Insert with some value:

```
 defp insert_item(params) do
    case Repo.insert(MyItem.changeset(%MyItem{}, %{"var1" => params})) do
      {:ok, item} -> item
      {:error, changeset} -> IO.inspect changeset.errors
    end
  end
```

Comment: You probably want to move the `nil` clause above `item` or else the `item` one will always match.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use this kind of function in multiple places, you can define a function for this in `MyApp.Repo` (If not, just copy this code into the controller you want to use this from). Add the following to `MyApp.Repo` module in `lib/my_app/repo.ex`:

```
def get_or_insert(schema, params) do
  case get_by(schema, params) do
    nil -> insert(schema.changeset(schema.__struct__, params))
    struct -> {:ok, struct}
  end
end
```

After that, you can do `MyApp.Repo.get_or_insert(MyItem, %{var1: "some value"})` and get back `{:ok, %MyItem{...}}` or `{:error, %Ecto.Changeset{}}`.

Demo:

```
iex(1)> Repo.all Post
[debug] QUERY OK db=1.2ms
SELECT p0."id", p0."title", p0."inserted_at", p0."updated_at" FROM "posts" AS p0 []
[]
iex(2)> Repo.get_or_insert Post, %{title: "foo"}
[debug] QUERY OK db=1.8ms queue=0.1ms
SELECT p0."id", p0."title", p0."inserted_at", p0."updated_at" FROM "posts" AS p0 WHERE (p0."title" = $1) ["foo"]
[debug] QUERY OK db=8.5ms
INSERT INTO "posts" ("title","inserted_at","updated_at") VALUES ($1,$2,$3) RETURNING "id" ["foo", {{2016, 9, 7}, {10, 6, 52, 0}}, {{2016, 9, 7}, {10, 6, 52, 0}}]
{:ok,
 %MyApp.Post{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "posts">, id: 1,
  inserted_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-09-07 10:06:52>, title: "foo",
  updated_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-09-07 10:06:52>}}
iex(3)> Repo.get_or_insert Post, %{title: "foo"}
[debug] QUERY OK db=1.8ms decode=2.6ms
SELECT p0."id", p0."title", p0."inserted_at", p0."updated_at" FROM "posts" AS p0 WHERE (p0."title" = $1) ["foo"]
{:ok,
 %MyApp.Post{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "posts">, id: 1,
  inserted_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-09-07 10:06:52>, title: "foo",
  updated_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-09-07 10:06:52>}}
iex(4)> Repo.get_or_insert Post, %{title: "bar"}
[debug] QUERY OK db=2.0ms
SELECT p0."id", p0."title", p0."inserted_at", p0."updated_at" FROM "posts" AS p0 WHERE (p0."title" = $1) ["bar"]
[debug] QUERY OK db=8.0ms
INSERT INTO "posts" ("title","inserted_at","updated_at") VALUES ($1,$2,$3) RETURNING "id" ["bar", {{2016, 9, 7}, {10, 6, 59, 0}}, {{2016, 9, 7}, {10, 6, 59, 0}}]
{:ok,
 %MyApp.Post{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "posts">, id: 2,
  inserted_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-09-07 10:06:59>, title: "bar",
  updated_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-09-07 10:06:59>}}
iex(5)> Repo.get_or_insert Post, %{title: "bar"}
[debug] QUERY OK db=2.2ms
SELECT p0."id", p0."title", p0."inserted_at", p0."updated_at" FROM "posts" AS p0 WHERE (p0."title" = $1) ["bar"]
{:ok,
 %MyApp.Post{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "posts">, id: 2,
  inserted_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-09-07 10:06:59>, title: "bar",
  updated_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-09-07 10:06:59>}}
```